# export lotus document to excel : excel convert string to date

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, export-to-excel, lotusscript

I export a text-field by `lotusscript` to `excel` but in excel has convert my text to date type.

for sample:

> lotusscript : text-field = "2016/01/28" ----> excel : date-type =
>   "28/01/2016"

howto export to `excel` with `"2016/01/28"`

thank you

Comment: try use single quote `'` before date string `lotusscript : text-field = "'2016/01/28"`..

Comment: Set an explicit cell format (Cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "@" )

Comment: thank you everyone. I use method numberFormat = "@" before set value to excel and they are completely in text-type form. XD

Comment: It would help if you showed your code.